# in two dimensional array in c++ why we always have to mention number of columns?

Tags: c++, arrays

this is a very simple question but whoever i ask it they cant answer it.
in two dimensional arrays we have to specify rows and columns,right?
for example:

```
void foo( int towers **[ ][ 3 ]** , int rings )
{
  for (int ring = 0; ring < rings; ring++)
  {
    ... towers[ ring ][ 0 ]...
  }
}
```

in programming its okay if we dont write(mention) rows as you see in that piece of code,but we ALWYAS have to write number of columns no matter what.
so what is the logic reason that why we should write number of columns? what will happen if we dont?

Comment: you can think as if you are passing an array of pointers where each pointer is pointing to a row. Thus you can also pass 2D array as "Func(int (*towers)[3])"

Comment: what i meant was in general,this piece of code was just an example.

Comment: Above reason is true in general too. If you have "Y" number of columns you can still accept a 2D array as "Func(int (*arr2)[Y]){}". :). This is just another way.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you try to access a two dimensional array, you specify the two indices: array[a][b].  C++ ensures all the elements in `array[n][...]` are contiguous in memory for any `n`, then the next bit of memory is used for `array[n+1][...]` etc..  For example:

```
               array[0][0]  ((T*)array)
               array[0][1]  ((T*)array) + 1
               array[0][2]  ((T*)array) + 2
               array[1][0]  ((T*)array) + 3
               array[1][1]  ((T*)array) + 4
               ...
```

So, the absolute memory address of array[a][b], in an array T array[A][B] is:

```
((T*)array) + a * B + b;
```

See how the calculation needs B but not A?  Similarly, the compiler is insisting you provide all but the left-most index.

In some ways, it would be nice if the compiler verified that you didn't try to index to a value of [a] at or past A, but the language makes no such checks - it's up to the programmer to ensure their code indexes the array safely.  If you want safety you can use a `std::vector<>` and `at()` for runtime index checking, or even write a fixed-size-array mechanism that checks compile-time-constant indices at compile time (not very useful, as indices typically vary at runtime).

Comment: thank you,but a friend of mine mentioned that cause when it compile the [] get deleted(sorry i dont know how to explain it better) and thus it make confusion since there might be two arrays with the same size after the elimination of [] ,then it dont know to assign values to which array.

Comment: @sam: I can't understand your explanation of your friend's point well enough to comment on it properly. Peripherally, when calling code calls say `foo(my_towers, 4)` it's "promising" `foo` that it's safe and meaningful to use the data for `0 <= a < rings`. `my_towers` itself might be `int my_towers[4][3]`, or `int my_towers[15][3]` but shouldn't be smaller ala `int my_towers[3][3]`. The caller is telling `foo` which array to use: `my_towers` - it can not get confused with some other array.

Answer (score 1):

You know how two dimensional array is stored in the memory. If it is of size [n][m] then it just takes n x m consecutive cells in the memory. Afterwords when you get asked about element [a][b] there is the calculation that takes the element a * m + b from these consecutive cells. However this calculation can not be performed if you do not supply the number of columns (because otherwise the m will not be known).

On the other hand the number of columns and rows is not stored in the memory portion for the array and the number of columns can not be derived from the memory either. All this means that the computer will not know which memory address to serve you.